# 'findMany' filter search in deeply nested table in Prisma

Tags: prisma

How can I make filtered search in my DB with Prisma?

I want to: find Offers only with certain 'Category' 'title' (for example - 'Fruits')

I got such DB schema:

```js
model Offer {
  id             String            @id
  available      Boolean
  title          String
  price          Int
  quantity       Int?
  categories     OfferCategory[]
  createdAt      DateTime          @default(now())
  description    OfferDescription?
}

model OfferCategory {
  id         Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  offer      Offer    @relation(fields: [offerId], references: [id])
  offerId    String
  category   Category @relation(fields: [categoryId], references: [id])
  categoryId String

  @@map("offercategory")
}

model Category {
  id          String          @id
  title       String?
  metaTitle   String?
  slug        String?
  description String?
  parentId    String?
  parent      Category?       @relation("CategoryHeritance", fields: [parentId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  kids        Category[]      @relation("CategoryHeritance")
  offers      OfferCategory[]

  @@map("category")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is answer for my qestion:

```
prisma.offer.findMany({
    where: {
      categories: { some: { category: { is: { title: 'Fruits'} } } },
    },
})
```